# Why does my green giant arborvitae have so many buds?

Tags: shrubs, evergreens

I have about 10 green giant evergreens and only one of them has what I call large buds on the tips of the branches. Why only this one shrub? Some branches are so loaded that they are drooping?

[image: green giant buds]

Answer (score 1):

Those large buds are seed pods. Usually a heavy crop is in response to stress. Perhaps not enough water or attack by insects.

Once the flowers are done the pods should look like this and turn to brown in later summer.
[image: Cedar seed pods courtesy Shutterstock]